# Creating slant gradient on div (both top and bottom)

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I'm trying to apply a gradient to a div which should look like this:

[image]

I've managed to figure out how to make the slant at the top, but unsure on how it can be achieved on the bottom.

**Current approach:**

```css
.gradient{
    background: linear-gradient(188deg, #FFFFFF 24%, transparent 24%), linear-gradient(90deg, #454545 0%, #454545 100%);
}

.gap{
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient">
  <div class="gap"></div>
</div>
```

I've tried to flip the gradient, i.e.

```
.gradient{
    background: linear-gradient(185deg, #FFFFFF 24%, transparent 24%), linear-gradient(90deg, #454545 0%, #454545 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(185deg, transparent 24%, #FFF 24%), linear-gradient(90deg, #454545 100%, #454545 0%);
}
```

But it didn't work and I don't think it's the right way to approach this (as in creating another linear gradient).

Comment: give background color to gap and use transform property of css, rotate or skew that fit best for you

Answer (score 3):

**OPTION 1**

HTML -

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```

CSS-

```css
.container{
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: skewY(20deg);
  background: #454545;
}
```

**OPTION 2 (Recommended)-**

HTML -

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```

CSS-

```css
.container{
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 25%, 100% 100%, 0 75%);
  background: #454545;
}
```

**Both Results to -**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use clip-path to achieve this.

Something like this

clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 22%, 100% 99%, 0 74%);

Here is a site that helps you get the right path: https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Answer (score 0):

Divide your shape into 3 parts. Two triangles and one rectangle:

```css
.box {
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 background:                                             /*Position /width height*/
  linear-gradient(to top right,grey 50%,transparent 50.5%)   top    /100%  30%,
  linear-gradient(grey,grey)                                 center /100%  40%,
  linear-gradient(to bottom left,grey 50%,transparent 50.5%) bottom /100%  30%;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Here is with different colors to better see the puzzle

```css
.box {
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 background:                                             /*Position /width height*/
  linear-gradient(to top right,red 50%,transparent 50.5%)   top    /100%  30%,
  linear-gradient(blue,blue)                                 center /100%  40%,
  linear-gradient(to bottom left,green 50%,transparent 50.5%) bottom /100%  30%;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```